# DataweAve Transformation: How to transform, concat, sum array of items

Tags: dataweave

Can you help transform the following input data into the given output:

INPUT:

```
[
{
    "ID_TYPE": "4",
    "DATE": "20230529",
    "ADM_TIME": "17:00",
    "PAYLOAD_NUMBER": "597418",
    "PAYLOAD_COMMENT": "HELLO"
},
{
    "ID_TYPE": "4",
    "DATE": "20230531",
    "ADM_TIME": "17:00",
    "PAYLOAD_NUMBER": "597418",
    "PAYLOAD_COMMENT": "HELLO"
},
{
    "ID_TYPE": "4",
    "DATE": "20230602",
    "ADM_TIME": "17:00",
    "PAYLOAD_NUMBER": "597418",
    "PAYLOAD_COMMENT": "HELLO"
},
{
    "ID_TYPE": "4",
    "DATE": "20230628",
    "ADM_TIME": "8:00",
    "PAYLOAD_NUMBER": "597500",
    "PAYLOAD_COMMENT": "Comments"
},
{
    "ID_TYPE": "4",
    "DATE": "20230628",
    "ADM_TIME": "17:00",
    "PAYLOAD_NUMBER": "597500",
    "PAYLOAD_COMMENT": "Comments"
},
{
    "ID_TYPE": "4",
    "DATE": "20230629",
    "ADM_TIME": "12:00",
    "PAYLOAD_NUMBER": "597500",
    "PAYLOAD_COMMENT": "Comments"
},
{
    "ID_TYPE": "4",
    "DATE": "20230630",
    "ADM_TIME": "17:00",
    "PAYLOAD_NUMBER": "597500",
    "PAYLOAD_COMMENT": "Comments"
},
{
    "ID_TYPE": "4",
    "DATE": "20230702",
    "ADM_TIME": "12:00",
    "PAYLOAD_NUMBER": "597500",
    "PAYLOAD_COMMENT": "Comments"
}
]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[
    {
            "TIMES": "17:00",
            "MORNING": "0",
            "NOON": "0",
            "EVENING": "3",
            "TOTAL_QUANTITY": "3",
            "DATES": "2023/05/29, 2023/06/02, 2023/05/31",
            "PAYLOAD_NUMBER": "597418",
            "PAYLOAD_COMMENT": "HELLO"
        },
        {
            "TIMES": "8:00, 12:00, 17:00",
            "MORNING": "1",
            "NOON": "2",
            "EVENING": "2",
            "TOTAL_QUANTITY": "5",
            "DATES": "2023/06/28, 2023/06/29, 2023/06/30, 2023/07/02",
            "PAYLAOD_NUMBER": "597500",
            "PAYLOAD_COMMENT": "Comments"
        }
    ]
```

Where the input is groupby PAYLOAD_NUMBER then:

- TIMES is a listing of ADM_TIME from the input data,
- MORNING, a count of TIMES between 00:01 to 09:59,
- NOON, a count of TIMES between 10:00 to 14:59,
- EVENING, count of TIMES between 15:00PM to 23:59,
- TOTAL_QUANTITY is the sum total between MORNING, NOON and EVENING,
- DATES is a listing of DATE.

Thank you.

Comment: You should indent the data for clarity.

Comment: What is the criteria for grouping the data from the input into the two records of the output?

Comment: The Input is groupby PAYLOAD_NUMBER then from that output the rest of the transformation is done. Thank you.

Comment: Your definition seems incomplete. `TIMES` in the first record shows only one value. Are you leaving only unique values? and then sorted?

Comment: Yes in the first record "TIMES": "17:00" because from the input the 3 records have the same value ADM_TIMES= "17:00". The result of Times is a concatenation of the values in ADM_TIMES. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and add these details. Also add what happens to time "00:00". It is not counted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use groupBy() then mapObject() to transform each group totalizing, sorting and formatting as needed, then pluck to get a list of the results.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun normalizeTime(t: String)= t as LocalTime  {format: "H:mm"} as String {format: "HH:mm"}
fun normalizeDate(d: String)= d as Date {format: "yyyyMMdd"} as String {format: "yyyy/MM/dd"}
---
payload 
    groupBy ($.PAYLOAD_NUMBER)
    mapObject ((value, key, index) -> (key): {
        TIMES: value.*ADM_TIME distinctBy $ orderBy normalizeTime($) joinBy " ",
        MORNING: sizeOf(value.ADM_TIME filter (normalizeTime($) >= "00:00" and normalizeTime($) <= "09:59" )),
        NOON: sizeOf(value.ADM_TIME filter (normalizeTime($) >= "10:00" and normalizeTime($) <= "14:59" )),
        EVENING: sizeOf(value.ADM_TIME filter (normalizeTime($) >= "15:00" and normalizeTime($) <= "23:59" )),
        TOTAL_QUANTITY: sizeOf(value),
        DATES: value.*DATE distinctBy $ orderBy $ map normalizeDate($) joinBy " ",
        PAYLAOD_NUMBER: key as String,
        PAYLOAD_COMMENT: value[0].PAYLOAD_COMMENT
    })
    pluck ($)
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "TIMES": "17:00",
    "MORNING": 0,
    "NOON": 0,
    "EVENING": 3,
    "TOTAL_QUANTITY": 3,
    "DATES": "2023/05/29 2023/05/31 2023/06/02",
    "PAYLAOD_NUMBER": "597418",
    "PAYLOAD_COMMENT": "HELLO"
  },
  {
    "TIMES": "8:00 12:00 17:00",
    "MORNING": 1,
    "NOON": 2,
    "EVENING": 2,
    "TOTAL_QUANTITY": 5,
    "DATES": "2023/06/28 2023/06/29 2023/06/30 2023/07/02",
    "PAYLAOD_NUMBER": "597500",
    "PAYLOAD_COMMENT": "Comments"
  }
]
```

I added the missing "00:00" time. Feel free to change. it